# Could dual-booting have been the cause of my issues?

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS "alongside" Windows 10 to make sure that Ubuntu would work well on my laptop (Acer Swift X) before fully committing to Ubuntu. I ended up getting scared and deleting Ubuntu because of some major issues, however.

My issues were the following:

1. My PC wouldn't start

   - After I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, it would literally take 5 - 15 minutes of randomly pressing the power-button until the laptop finally turned on. This has never happened before.
2. Whenever I closed the laptop lid (in Ubuntu), the PC would shut off instead of going into sleep mode. I even installed gnome-tweaks and made sure the suspend on laptop lid close setting was on.

   - It should be said that the Acer Swift X has known sleep-problems. Even in windows, it doesn't always turn off right away when closing the lid, and can randomly turn on and/or crash with the lid closed.

**My question to you is the following:** Do you think I most likely wouldn't have these issues if I did a "fresh install" of Ubuntu instead of dual-booting?

Comment: Hello. When you boot from the Live Media there are 2 options. Try and install. The try is there so you can try it out before you commit. This does not mean there will not be ANY issues but will tell you if the OS will run. It seems that you may have had 2 issues after the install. It would have been a better idea to have addressed them then to delete the Ubuntu OS. Dual booting may not have caused the issues at all but you never tried to solve them to find out. You yourself have said that the 2 nd item is a know issue in multiple OS s.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer. I agree, that would have been better. I got so scared I had messed up my computer that I didn't troubleshoot for as long as I should have. The seccond issue isn't as bad on Windows as it was on Ubuntu though, it doesn't happen every time on windows, for example.

Comment: So .. Install Ubuntu 20.04 again and this time use the try option first. After the install ignore item 2 and ask for help with item one if it happens again.

Comment: Dual booting is usually more dangerous to your other OS and data than to a computer(deletion of data if not careful with installing).  Would google ubuntu and your PC model to see if any problems ubuntu has with it when installing, might find good tips to make life easier.  Also back up your data first, it is easier to do than trying to retrieve it after loss.

Comment: Thanks crip, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you boot from the Live Media there are 2 options. Try and install.

The try is there so you can try it out before you commit. This does not mean there will not be ANY issues but will tell you if the OS will run.

It seems that you may have had 2 issues after the install. It would have been a better idea to have addressed them then to delete the Ubuntu OS.

Dual booting may not have caused the issues at all but you never tried to solve them to find out. You yourself have said that the 2 nd item is a known issue in multiple OS s.

So .. Install Ubuntu 20.04 again and this time use the try option first.

After the install ignore item 2 and ask for help with item one if it happens again.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: If you like the answer you can accept it and or up vote it.